# Create own Wordpress shortcode gallery

Tags: php, gallery, shortcode

How I can handle this shortcode:
[my_gallery]
img01.jpg
img02.jpg
img03.jpg
img04.jpg
[/my_gallery]

I can't understand how to write a function, to handle image files name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you going to put newlines in there between each image? or just spaces?
I'll put in both for this example, checking if there's a newline.

You would want something like this in your functions.php:

```
add_shortcode('my_gallery', 'gallery_function');
function gallery_function($atts, $code=''){
   $files=preg_split( '/\s+/', $code ); // Added in from Jan's comment.

   foreach($files as $img){
      if($img=="")
          continue; // ensures that no empty items from the split have entered in, since that is possible with the preg_split
      //handle each filename in here.
   }
}
```

It's not perfect.. if you use both spaces and newlines in your shortcode, it'll mess things up - though that could be dealt with in more detail inside the function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: With a regular expression you can split on either a newline or a space character. `preg_split( '/[\n ]+/', $code )`, or even just `preg_split( '/\s+/', $code )` to split on any whitespace character.

Comment: Thanks for that Jan, i'm not all that confident in my regex skills, so I opted not to go that route for fear of giving a faulty example. But yeah that would be the preferred route is to add in regex to cover different ways of doing it.

Comment: Updated to include the preg_split with whitespace, then put in a check to ensure there was actually a potential file name in the loop.

Comment: @Mike: If you use the `preg_split()` you don't need to detect the marker either.

Comment: @Jan: Ah! Thanks :) I completely forgot about that, updated.

Comment: @Mike In this case, output only first image img01.jpg :( [my_gallery]
img01.jpg
img02.jpg
[/my_gallery]